# Split PHP script function in two parts and close the first script asap while the second is still executing

Tags: php

I have a PHP script, which is called from another program. But inside this script, there is a function, which sometimes required a longer execution time.
The program, which called the script, is waiting until the script has finished. That creates sometimes problems.
So I am looking for a possibility to extract the part with the longer execution time and put it inside another PHP script.
I found a solution with curl to call the second PHP script. But I am not sure, if these is solving my problem!

```
$output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

After execute `$output = curl_exec($ch);` is the first `PHP` script waiting for any response from the second script?
In this case the split of the script would not help!

Or how can I finish the first script while the second one is still continue to work?

Comment: You can close the HTTP connection and still keep a PHP script running after that, so that could possibly help with the cURL approach. There might be better ways, perhaps, but to evaluate that, your description of the issue is a big thin yet.